App uses a user token to listen messages from telegram but receive delayed message
I'm write a application to listen message from all channels, which my account subscribe on telegram. It's use user token (not bot).
My issue is with normal channels, messages received from telegram delivery very fast, immediately. But with some channels (has 100k - 300k users), messages from telegram was delayed 5m - 20m. I'm using Golang sdk with MTproto
client := telegram.NewClient(123456, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", opts)
    return client.Run(context.Background(), func(ctx context.Context) error {
        if err := client.Auth().IfNecessary(ctx, auth.NewFlow(terminal.Terminal{
            PhoneNumber: "0123456789",
        }, auth.SendCodeOptions{})); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Cannot authenticate user by flow, error: %v\n", err)
            return err
        }

        user, err := client.Self(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Cannot get self, error: %v\n", err)
            return err
        }

        return gaps.Run(ctx, client.API(), user.ID, updates.AuthOptions{
            OnStart: func(ctx context.Context) {
                log.Println("Start listen code from telegram ..")
            },
        })
    })

Messages from telegram delivery immediately without delay
